# How to generate similar to Qt documentation via Doxygen?

Tags: qt, qt4, doxygen

The default Doxygen HTML output produces [this](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html) kind of documentation.

Is it possible to make the HTML output similar to [Qt3](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qwidget.html) or [Qt4](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html) documentation style? How to achieve this?

Qt4 style is preferred, however Qt3 also will do.

Comment: Doxygen already produces quite similar output (if you look at the content), so what aspects do you want to change? and what parts are ok as they are? or do want exactly the same layout and style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30535-Doxygen-and-Qt...-is-there-a-FAQ?p=143676#post143676

Sorry busy to write full answer

Comment: I have already tried that, it produces not quite similar output. But thanks for answering

Comment: The URL is invalid now.